# Parsing information in a CString

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am having trouble getting the algorithm down right when I am parsing information in a cstring.

I have an datafile that is similar to this.

```
Hammer 1 1.00
 Drill 2 2.00
Saw  3 3.00
Level 4  4.00
Pick 5 5.00 
Nail 6 6.00
Mallet 7 7.00
Putty 8 8.00
Stapler 9 9.00
Desk 10 10.00
Table 11 11.00
Marker 12 12.00
```

The data file could have spaces to start each line or between each value.
The format of this data file would be Name,Quantity,and Price. Where when parsed correctly each Name, Quantity, and Price are stored in an array of structures.

I need to use cstrings on this question, because I am learning them from a book right now.

This is my algorithm so far and I think I get caught in a while loop somewhere where my program just hangs.

For my code the way it is, my thoughts are. While the value at `readLineIndex` of the line that was from the data file is not a null character then do the inside. If the cstring had a blank line anywhere in the cstring add one to my `readLineIndex`, if the character is alphanumeric copy it into a temp array and move onto the next character and repeat the above until you get a blank space. Once the program hits a blank space store that value into the correct array of structures variable. The program would know what value it is at by counting since there is only 3 variables I am getting from the input file I would just say if the first variable that I retreive is 1 on my counter then store it into array[structureCounter].product, if it is 2 store it into array[structureCounter].quantity, if it is 3 store it into array[structureCounter].unitPrice. Also structureCounter only goes up by one every time the parsing is done and the reading of the file is not at the end of line.

This is how my function is getting called. MAX_INVENTORY = 12.

```
        while(!inFile.getline(readLine, MAX_CHARACTERS, '\n').eof() && structureCounter < MAX_INVENTORY)
    {
        parseInformation(readLine,inventory, readLineIndex, structureCounter);
        structureCounter += 1;
    }
```

Function algorithm.

```
void parseInformation(OneLine readLine,OneItem inventory[], int & readLineIndex, int & structureCounter)
{
    int tempIndex = 0;
    int valueCounter = 0;
    OneLine tempArray;
    while(readLine[readLineIndex] != '\0')
    {
        while(readLine[readLineIndex] == ' ')
        {

            readLineIndex += 1;

        }
        while(isalnum(readLine[readLineIndex]))
        {   

            tempArray[tempIndex] = readLine[readLineIndex];

            tempIndex += 1;
            readLineIndex += 1;

        }
        if(valueCounter == 0)
        {   
            strcpy(inventory[structureCounter].product,tempArray);
            valueCounter += 1;

        }
        if(valueCounter == 1)
        {
            inventory[structureCounter].quantity = atoi(tempArray);
            valueCounter += 1;

        }
        if (valueCounter == 2)
        {

            inventory[structureCounter].unitPrice = atof(tempArray);

        }
    }   
    return;
```

Comment: For clarification, is this regarding a `CString` (MFC data structure / C#), a `std::string` (C++) or a C-Style string (array of characters terminated by nul character)?

Comment: Sorry about that. It is a C-Style string (C++)

Comment: You can use `sscanf()` to parse a C string.

Comment: Can you switch to `std::string`?  You could use `std::getline` to read in the line of text and various methods to parse the data out of the string.  Search StackOverflow for "c++ read file struct" or "c++ read file separated values".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Read the line that starts with "I need to use cstrings"

Comment: I cannot switch to a string class string.

Comment: You're not adding a null terminator to `tempArray` before calling `strcpy`.

Comment: @Barmar sweet but I think that still doesnt fix my parsing algorithm. I tried to see if it worked after that fix but it doesn't.

Comment: That was just the first problem I noticed. See my answer for all the mistakes you made. If you stepped through the code in the debugger you might have noticed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're not adding a null terminator to `tempArray` before you call `strcpy`. Second, after you copy `tempArray`, you need to reset `tempIndex` back to `0` so you can use it for the next field. Third, after you copy from `tempArray` to `product`, you're incrementing `valueCounter` from `0` to `1`. So the next test `if (valueCounter == 1)` will succeed and it will try to put the parsed `tempArray` into `quantity`; then you'll increment it to `2`, the next test will succeed, and you'll try to put it into `unitPrice`. You should use `else if` or a `switch` statement so you only do one of them; you could also increment `valueCounter` **after** you do all the tests.

```
void parseInformation(OneLine readLine,OneItem inventory[], int & readLineIndex, int & structureCounter) {
    int tempIndex = 0;
    int valueCounter = 0;
    OneLine tempArray;
    while(readLine[readLineIndex] != '\0') {
        while(readLine[readLineIndex] == ' ') {
            readLineIndex += 1;
        }
        while(isalnum(readLine[readLineIndex])) {   
            tempArray[tempIndex] = readLine[readLineIndex];
            tempIndex += 1;
            readLineIndex += 1;
        }
        tempArray[tempIndex] = 0; // Add null terminator
        switch (valueCounter) {
        case 0:
            strcpy(inventory[structureCounter].product,tempArray);
            break;
        case 1:
            inventory[structureCounter].quantity = atoi(tempArray);
            break;
        case 2:
            inventory[structureCounter].unitPrice = atof(tempArray);
            break;
        }
        valueCounter++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so where would I add my null terminator? When I define `tempArray` so `OneLine tempArray = '\0'`. Just kind of confused on the comment in your code.

Comment: The line `tempArray[tempIndex] = 0` adds the null terminator. Read the comment!

Comment: I found a infite loop `while(isalnum(readLine[readLineIndex])) 
  {   
            tempArray[tempIndex] = readLine[readLineIndex];
            tempIndex += 1;
            readLineIndex += 1;
   
        }`      I found it by trying to print out a bunch of "H"s and before I did that my program would just hang still just waiting. I had the same logic but don't know why it is like that seems right in my head.